# Why is apply not much slower than %*% in R?

Tags: r, loops, optimization, sum

Here is example code with output:

```
set.seed(234)
a <- matrix(rnorm(100000), 10000,100)
dim(a)

fo1 <- function() apply(a, 1, sum)
fo2 <- function() a %*% rep(1, 100)
fo3 <- function() {
    n <- nrow(a)
    x <- numeric(n)
    for(i in seq_len(n))  x[i] <- sum(a[i, ])
    }
fo4 <- function() rowSums(a)

# install.packages("microbenchmark")
require(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(fo1 , fo2, fo3, fo4 ,times = 100000)
# expr min lq median uq    max neval
#  fo1  81 90     91 96 188969 1e+05
#  fo2  75 87     90 94 241332 1e+05
#  fo3  75 84     87 91 271085 1e+05
#  fo4  72 88     91 97 39447 1e+05
```

I thought that apply and loops should be slower than the vectorized version, or the dedicated rowSums function - but they all seem to give very similar results (except for the max value).

Could any one suggest why this is the case?

Comment: fwiw try .rowSums with manual nrow,ncol args

Comment: You're evaluating the time it takes to look up  the function, not the actual function call. Try `microbenchmark(fo1(), fo2()...)`.

Comment: I am parallely embarrassed for my mistake - thanks for catching it Martin!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Martin noted, you are not calling the functions in microbenchmark. Also, the function `fo3` doesn't return anything:

```
fo3 <- function() {
    n <- nrow(a)
    x <- numeric(n)
    for(i in seq_len(n))  x[i] <- sum(a[i, ])
    x #you missed this
}
```

And `fo2` returns matrix whereas other functions return vector. So let's use

```
fo2 <- function() c(a %*% rep(1, 100))
```

Here are correct results:

```
microbenchmark(fo1() , fo2(), fo3(), fo4() ,times = 100)
Unit: milliseconds
  expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 fo1() 33.437565 37.859724 39.961079 41.409828 85.950181   100
 fo2()  1.756187  1.820632  1.861232  1.899416  2.138938   100
 fo3() 35.356449 37.069169 37.713325 39.624361 51.001235   100
 fo4()  2.467656  2.529235  2.561986  2.616621  2.884215   100
```

You see that the matrix-vector multiplication is fastest, although the difference with `rowSums` is really small (calling the internal `.rowSums` instead doesn't affect the results). The differences between `apply` and `for` loop approach are also small, as `apply` is just a loop in disguise.

Note that

```
> identical(fo1(),fo2())
[1] FALSE
> identical(fo1(),fo3())
[1] TRUE
> identical(fo1(),fo4())
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(fo1(),fo2())
[1] TRUE
```

The matrix multiplication version gives slightly different results than others.

Comment: Might as well check that those functions are returning the same result; no sense comparing apples and oranges!

Comment: @Matrin thanks, corrected. Didn't affect the results though.

Comment: `identical` and `all.equal` only compare two arguments, so you need to compare results pair-wise.

Comment: Oops, I did that first and then though to be clever and combine the results. Accidentally got the right logical values :)